# What goes into AndroidManifest of a library project?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I have an Android library that contains an activity. Yet it does not appear to matter whether I include the activity in the  element or not. As long as I put the full 'path' to the activity in my application that uses the library is done, I can run the activity.

Also, the package value in the manifest seems to be arbitrary. It does not have to correspond to the java package of the library classes. It seems to only be used by the generation of the R values.

What SHOULD the package value be in my AndroidManifest of the library project?
When (if ever) do I need to include some information in the  element?

Comment: Maybe, the `uses-permission` section. And (I guess) very little more than this. (no application, no activity). The services, if your library uses them.

Comment: No such entry is required in your manifest if it is a library module because if you will include it, at the time of merging manifest your IDE will throw an error, it will get conflicts in icon, sdk value, and other stuff, so it is a good practice not to include any such thing in manifest of lib module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What SHOULD the package value be in my AndroidManifest of the library project?

Something reasonably unique, so it does not collide with other libraries that the app might use. Otherwise, AFAIK, the value only controls code generation (e.g., `R`), as you noted.

> When (if ever) do I need to include some information in the element?

I do not know what "the element" is.

> What goes into AndroidManifest of a library project?

Anything that the library wants to merge into the app's manifest:

- Components (e.g., `<activity>`) that the hosting app is sure to need
- `<uses-permission>` elements, for any permissions required by the library
- `<uses-feature>` elements, for any hardware features required by the library
- And so on

If your app is the only app that will be using the library, the dividing line between what goes into the library's manifest and what goes into the app's manifest is really up to you and is somewhat arbitrary. If, OTOH, the library will be used by multiple apps, particularly ones that you are not writing, try to craft the library's manifest to minimize headaches for the app developers:

- Forcing app developers to add manifest entries, for things that are always needed, is a headache
- Forcing app developers to add manifest-merger control attributes (e.g., `tools:replace`), because the library asks for things that the app does not need, is a headache
- Adding things in the manifest that weaken app security (e.g., unnecessary `<intent-filter>` elements) is a headache
- And so on

Comment: CommonsWare: The element I was referring to is the required <application> element which is now <application />

Comment: @BrianReinhold: In terms of attributes... probably few if any. Looking over [the list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), most if not all of those are the app's responsibility. If the library is really some sort of app framework (where the app itself is tiny and the library has most of the code), then that changes things. But child elements of `<application>` may be relevant: components, `<meta-data>` for API keys, etc.

Comment: @CommonWare: You seem to be really good at this so I will ask one more question; this is a Bluetooth library, do I need to have the Bluetooth permission in the library manifest or is it sufficient to put them (only) in the application's manifest?

Comment: @BrianReinhold: If your library depends upon Bluetooth, or it could really use Bluetooth but could live without it, put the relevant `<uses-permission>` and `<uses-feature>` elements in the library's manifest. If Bluetooth is a side feature, that apps using the library are unlikely to use, then perhaps leave them out of the library's manifest.